# Whats a good command-oriented commandline framework for Python 2 and 3?

Tags: python, command-line, python-3.x

I like the cmdln framework for writing programs that work like `svn command argument` but it only works in Python 2. What's a good Python 3 alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `argparse` module from Python's standard library also supports commands, and it works in both, Python 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

If you like `cmdln` you can still use it, I think: using the `2to3` tool on `cmdln.py` and the examples `p4.py` and `svn.py` seems to produce working code.  The 2-ness of `cmdln.py` seems limited to minor syntactic issues and naming.  Snipping random bits from the diff:

```
-LOOP_ALWAYS, LOOP_NEVER, LOOP_IF_EMPTY = range(3)
+LOOP_ALWAYS, LOOP_NEVER, LOOP_IF_EMPTY = list(range(3))

-            except CmdlnUserError, ex:
+            except CmdlnUserError as ex:

-                            line = raw_input(self._prompt_str)
+                            line = input(self._prompt_str)

-        for marker, preprocessor in preprocessors.items():
+        for marker, preprocessor in list(preprocessors.items()):

-        func = handler.im_func
-        if func.func_defaults:
-            func_defaults = list(func.func_defaults)
+        func = handler.__func__
+        if func.__defaults__:
+            func_defaults = list(func.__defaults__)

-        co_argcount = handler.im_func.func_code.co_argcount
+        co_argcount = handler.__func__.__code__.co_argcount

-        if DEBUG: print "dedent: indent=%d: %r" % (indent, line)
+        if DEBUG: print("dedent: indent=%d: %r" % (indent, line))
```

Etc.  After transformation, you should be able to get the expected output:

```
localhost-2:examples $ python3 p4.py add 
p4 add: opts={'filetype': None, 'changelist': None} paths=()
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in [Cement](http://cement.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Cliff](http://cliff.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) looks full-featured, is actively maintained, and runs on 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: This would be my first choice for many applications, just not the one I'm working on right now.